# How to provide a link to a file in grails Project Documentation

Tags: grails

In our project we use the in built [grails project documentation system](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/conf.html#docengine).

I currently have a file which I'd like to  provide a link to - ie. a simple 'click here to view the image'.

However, it seems the doc engine only supports:

- External links

  - e.g. `[Pivotal|http://www.gopivotal.com/oss]` or `"Pivotal":http://www.gopivotal.com/oss`
- Links to other sections in the document

  - e.g. `[Intro|guide:introduction]` or `[renderPDF|controllers]`
- Links to api doco

  - e.g. `[String|api:java.lang.String]`

**So how do I link to a simple local file?** (And ideally in a relative way, as the file of interest is in the src/docs directory, but will obviously be in a different absolute location when on different machines.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To link to a file in the images directory of the guide doc (with a relative link) use:

```
"click here to view the image":../img/the_image.png
```